# How to select denormalized ingredient data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, denormalized

I am making product inventory and showing data using below statement

```
SELECT _PRODNAME      AS [Manufacture Product], 
       _BASEPRODNAME  AS [Sub Product], 
       _PRDDEFQTY     AS [Required Qty / Unit], 
       _PURQTY        AS [Purchase Qty], 
       _PURRETQTY     AS [Return Qty], 
       _ISSUEQTY      AS [Issue Qty], 
       _DAMAGEQTY     AS [Damage Qty], 
       _BALQTY        AS [Balance Qty], 
       _MINESTIMATE   AS [Estimate Qty], 
       _SALEQTY       AS [Sale Qty], 
       _MANUDAMAGEQTY AS Damage, 
       _AVAILQTY      AS [Avail Qty] 
FROM   dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
```

This query is returning this result:

[image]

but my expected result is

[image]

in my sample data Vanilla Cake is main product and Butter Cream, Eggs, Flour are sub product, columns 3,4,5,6,7,8 are for sub product data and Columns 9,10,11,12 are for main product.

My question is how to show this data separately, I don't have any idea to this.

**Edit For Bounty**

As you see in the first Image there are two Manufacture Products 1) Manu 2) Vanila Cake

here we will get vanila cake Example :

Vanila cake has 3 Sub Product 1) Butter Cream 2) Eggs 3) Flour

Column No 3 to 8 are related to Sub product (Required Qty / Unit Column To Balance Qty Column)

Column No 9 to 12 are related to Manufacture product (Estimate Qty Column To Avail Qty Column)

Expected Result is shown in Image 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this more concisely with `GROUPING SETS` ([Demo](http://rextester.com/LVUGH16615))

```
SELECT [Manufacture Product] = _PRODNAME,
       [Sub Product] = _BASEPRODNAME,
       [Required Qty / Unit] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 0 THEN SUM(_PRDDEFQTY) END,
       [Purchase Qty] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 0 THEN SUM(_PURQTY) END,
       [Return Qty] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 0 THEN SUM(_PURRETQTY) END,
       [Issue Qty] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 0 THEN SUM(_ISSUEQTY) END,
       [Damage Qty] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 0 THEN SUM(_DAMAGEQTY) END,
       [Balance Qty] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 0 THEN SUM(_BALQTY) END,
       [Estimate Qty] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 1 THEN SUM(_MINESTIMATE) END,
       [Sale Qty] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 1 THEN SUM(_SALEQTY) END,
       Damage = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 1 THEN SUM(_MANUDAMAGEQTY) END,
       [Avail Qty] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) = 1 THEN SUM(_AVAILQTY) END    
FROM   dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( _PRODNAME ), ( _PRODNAME, _BASEPRODNAME ) )
ORDER  BY [Manufacture Product] ASC,
          GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME) DESC,
          [Sub Product] ASC
```

Just add a `WHERE _PRODNAME = 'Vanila Cake'` if needed.

---

Or alternatively you could get rid of the repeated `CASE` expressions with

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT [Manufacture Product] = _PRODNAME,
                [Sub Product] = _BASEPRODNAME,
                [Required Qty / Unit] = SUM(_PRDDEFQTY),
                [Purchase Qty] = SUM(_PURQTY),
                [Return Qty] = SUM(_PURRETQTY),
                [Issue Qty] = SUM(_ISSUEQTY),
                [Damage Qty] = SUM(_DAMAGEQTY),
                [Balance Qty] = SUM(_BALQTY),
                [Estimate Qty] = SUM(_MINESTIMATE),
                [Sale Qty] = SUM(_SALEQTY),
                Damage = SUM(_MANUDAMAGEQTY),
                [Avail Qty] = SUM(_AVAILQTY),
                GrpFlag = GROUPING(_BASEPRODNAME)
         FROM   VIEW_MANUFACTURING
         GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( _PRODNAME ), ( _PRODNAME, _BASEPRODNAME ) ))
SELECT T.[Manufacture Product],
       T.[Sub Product],
       OA1.*,
       OA2.*
FROM   T
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT [Required Qty / Unit],[Purchase Qty],[Return Qty],[Issue Qty],[Damage Qty],[Balance Qty]
                    WHERE  GrpFlag = 0) OA1
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT [Estimate Qty],[Sale Qty], Damage, [Avail Qty]
                    WHERE  GrpFlag = 1) OA2
ORDER  BY [Manufacture Product] ASC,
          GrpFlag DESC,
          [Sub Product] ASC
```

Comment: Received Expected result with little bit change

Answer (score 5):

You should really do this type of manipulation in the application layer.  Why?  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets -- unless you specifically specify an ordering.  You have not specified an ordering.

Second, all the columns of a SQL query should have the same number of columns.  You seem to want a different number for different rows.

One partial solution is to only put the name on the "first" row:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by _prodname order by _baseprodname) = 1
            then _prodname
        end) as [Manufacture Product],
       . . .
from dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
order by _prodname, _baseprodname;
```

To put them on different rows, you could do:

```
select v.[Manufacture Product], v.[Sub Product], . . .
from (select vm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by _prodname order by _baseprodname) as seqnum
      from dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING vm
     ) vm outer apply
     (values (1, _ProdName, NULL, NULL, . . .),
             (2, NULL, _BaseProdName, . . .)
     ) v(seqnum, [Manufacture Product], [Sub Product], . . .)
where vm.seqnum = 1 or v.seqnum = 2
order by v.[Manufacture Product], v.seqnum, v.[Sub Product];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked your sample, but problem is it's not dividing main and sub-product info, please see my updated question, I posted needed images

Comment: @ImranAliKhan . . . The second version does.

Comment: I removed all , . . . from codes but its giving me Msg 10709, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The number of columns for each row in a table value constructor must be the same.

Comment: @ImranAliKhan . . . You have to fill out the `NULL`s for "1" so they match the columns for "2".

Comment: It would be better off doing in drill down or application layer. Did you tried with union all replacing null values with empty string ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff with your solution [Manufacture Product] details are coming in the last row, it should be the first Row, and it is suitable only when I have one [Manufacture Product], If I have more then one [Manufacture Product] then as per your solution all sub-products are coming in top and all [Manufacture Product] are coming in last

Answer (score 3):

In this example, I take the distinct product that is not a 'Manu' (manufacturer).  To ensure the ordering of the first row of your desired output, I give the row a suborder integer = 1, for column `theOrder`.  I subquery the 'Manu' data, assume you want averages, this is for the Manufacturer Product row for 'Vanilla Cake'.

I UNION ALL this with the sub product details, giving it a suborder int = 2, `theOrder`.  Columns that are blanked in your desired output I leave NULL.

This entire thing is subqueried and I do case statements to blank out columns, similar to your desired output.  This is ordered using a combination of Manufacturer Product name and `theOrder` column, hence main products should be listed first followed by sub products.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE ([Manufacture Product] varchar(100), [Sub Product] varchar(100), [Required Qty / Unit] decimal(16,2), [Purchase Qty] decimal(16,2)
                    , [Return Qty] decimal(16,2)
                    ,[Issue Qty] decimal(16,2), [Damage Qty] decimal(16,2), [Balance Qty] decimal(16,2), [Estimate Qty] decimal(16,2)
                    ,[Sale Qty] decimal(16,2), [Damage] decimal(16,2), [Avail Qty] decimal(16,2))

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES ('manu',         '2 GOOD'     , 34.00, 502.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 502.00, 14.71, 0.00, 0.00, 14.71)
      ,('manu',         'CHOCO AL...', 34.00, 500.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 500.00, 14.71, 0.00, 0.00, 14.71)
      ,('Vanila Cake', 'Butter Cream', 10.00, 600.00, 0.00, 72.00, 0.00, 528.00, 52.80, 0.00, 0.00, 52.80)            
      ,('Vanila Cake', 'Eggs'        ,  2.00,1000.00, 0.00, 37.00, 0.00, 963.00, 52.80, 0.00, 0.00, 52.80)
      ,('Vanila Cake', 'Flour'       ,  5.00,   0.00, 0.00,  0.00, 0.00, 500.00, 52.80, 0.00, 0.00, 52.80)



SELECT CASE WHEN theOrder = 1  THEN [Manufacture Product] ELSE '' END [Manufacture Product]
      ,CASE WHEN theOrder = 2 THEN [Sub Product] ELSE '' END [Sub Product]
      ,[Required Qty / Unit]
      ,[Purchase Qty]
      ,[Return Qty]
      ,[Issue Qty]
      ,[Damage Qty]
      ,[Balance Qty]
      ,[Estimate Qty]
      ,[Sale Qty]
      ,Damage
      ,[Avail Qty]
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
               1 [theOrder]
              ,T.[Manufacture Product]
              ,'' [Sub Product]
              ,NULL [Required Qty / Unit]
              ,NULL [Purchase Qty]
              ,NULL [Return Qty]
              ,NULL [Issue Qty]
              ,NULL [Damage Qty]
              ,NULL [Balance Qty]
              ,(SELECT AVG(T2.[Estimate Qty]) FROM @temp T2 WHERE T2.[Manufacture Product] = 'Manu') [Estimate Qty]
              ,(SELECT AVG([Sale Qty]) FROM @temp T2 WHERE T2.[Manufacture Product] = 'Manu') [Sale Qty]
              ,(SELECT AVG([Damage]) FROM @temp T2 WHERE T2.[Manufacture Product] = 'Manu') [Damage]
              ,(SELECT AVG([Avail Qty]) FROM @temp T2 WHERE T2.[Manufacture Product] = 'Manu') [Avail Qty]

          FROM @temp T 
         WHERE T.[Manufacture Product] <> 'Manu'

        UNION ALL

          SELECT 2 [theOrder]
              ,T.[Manufacture Product]
              ,T.[Sub Product]
              ,T.[Required Qty / Unit]
              ,T.[Purchase Qty]
              ,T.[Return Qty]
              ,T.[Issue Qty]
              ,T.[Damage Qty]
              ,T.[Balance Qty]
              ,NULL [Estimate Qty]
              ,NULL [Sale Qty]
              ,NULL [Damage]
              ,NULL [Avail Qty]
          FROM @temp T
         WHERE T.[Manufacture Product] <> 'Manu'
        ) AS dT
ORDER BY dT.[Manufacture Product], dT.theOrder, dT.[Sub Product]
```

Which produces output similar to what you're asking.  The NULLS can be handled by the reporting tool.

FYI, I've done this easier in reporting tools like SSRS. If it were SSRS I would make a parent column for Manufacture Product.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this works as null values replaced by empty string and works for presentation how u would like to see in Image2.

Order by `Case statement` might get result set, please check and let me know

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT _PRODNAME AS [Manufacture Product]
        ,NULL [Sub Product]
        ,NULL [Required Qty / Unit]
        ,NULL [Purchase Qty]
        ,NULL [Return Qty]
        ,NULL [Issue Qty]
        ,NULL [Damage Qty]
        ,SUM(_BALQTY) AS [Balance Qty]
        ,SUM(_MINESTIMATE) AS [Estimate Qty]
        ,SUM(_SALEQTY) AS [Sale Qty]
        ,SUM(_MANUDAMAGEQTY) AS Damage
        ,SUM(_AVAILQTY) AS [Avail Qty]
    FROM dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
    GROUP BY _PRODNAME

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NULL AS [Manufacture Product]
        ,_BASEPRODNAME AS [Sub Product]
        ,NULL AS [Required Qty / Unit]
        ,NULL AS [Purchase Qty]
        ,NULL AS [Return Qty]
        ,NULL AS [Issue Qty]
        ,NULL AS [Damage Qty]
        ,NULL AS [Balance Qty]
        ,SUM(_MINESTIMATE) AS [Estimate Qty]
        ,SUM(_SALEQTY) AS [Sale Qty]
        ,SUM(_MANUDAMAGEQTY) AS Damage
        ,SUM(_AVAILQTY) AS [Avail Qty]
    FROM dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
    GROUP BY _BASEPRODNAME
    )
SELECT ISNULL([Manufacture Product], '') [Manufacture Product]
    ,ISNULL([Sub Product], '') [Sub Product]
    ,ISNULL([Required Qty / Unit], '') [Required Qty / Unit]
    ,ISNULL([Purchase Qty], '') [Purchase Qty]
    ,ISNULL([Return Qty], '') [Return Qty]
    ,ISNULL([Issue Qty], '') [Issue Qty]
    ,ISNULL([Damage Qty], '') [Damage Qty]
    ,ISNULL([Balance Qty], '') [Balance Qty]
    ,ISNULL([Estimate Qty], '') [Estimate Qty]
    ,ISNULL([Sale Qty], '') [Sale Qty]
    ,ISNULL(Damage, '') Damage
    ,ISNULL([Avail Qty], '') [Avail Qty]
FROM cte
 ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN [Sub Product] is null and [Manufacture Product] is not null  then [Manufacture Product] END DESC
         , CASE WHEN [Manufacture Product] IS NULL THEN [Sub Product] END
```

Comment: with your solution [Manufacture Product] details are coming in the last row, it should be the first Row, and it is suitable only when I have one [Manufacture Product], If I have more then one [Manufacture Product] then as per your solution all sub-products are coming in top and all [Manufacture Product] are coming in last

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for your problem if I understood your requirements correctly.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN record_type = 'Product' THEN _PRODNAME ELSE NULL END AS [Manufacture Product]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Sub Product' THEN _BASEPRODNAME ELSE NULL END AS [Sub Product]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Sub Product' THEN _PRDDEFQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Required Qty / Unit]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Sub Product' THEN _PURQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Purchase Qty]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Sub Product' THEN _PURRETQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Return Qty]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Sub Product' THEN _ISSUEQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Issue Qty]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Sub Product' THEN _DAMAGEQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Damage Qty]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Sub Product' THEN _BALQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Balance Qty]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Product' THEN _MINESTIMATE ELSE NULL END AS [Estimate Qty]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Product' THEN _SALEQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Sale Qty]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Product' THEN _MANUDAMAGEQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Damage]
    ,CASE WHEN record_type = 'Product' THEN _AVAILQTY ELSE NULL END AS [Avail Qty]
FROM (
    SELECT _PRODNAME
        ,NULL AS _BASEPRODNAME
        ,NULL AS _PRDDEFQTY
        ,NULL AS _PURQTY
        ,NULL AS _PURRETQTY
        ,NULL AS _ISSUEQTY
        ,NULL AS _DAMAGEQTY
        ,NULL AS _BALQTY
        ,_MINESTIMATE
        ,_SALEQTY
        ,_MANUDAMAGEQTY
        ,_AVAILQTY
        ,'Product' AS record_type
    FROM (
        SELECT _PRODNAME
            ,_BASEPRODNAME
            ,_PRDDEFQTY
            ,_PURQTY
            ,_PURRETQTY
            ,_ISSUEQTY
            ,_DAMAGEQTY
            ,_BALQTY
            ,_MINESTIMATE
            ,_SALEQTY
            ,_MANUDAMAGEQTY
            ,_AVAILQTY
            ,'Product' AS record_type
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY _PRODNAME ORDER BY _PRODNAME
                ) r_num
        FROM dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
        ) v
    WHERE r_num = 1
    UNION
    SELECT _PRODNAME
        ,_BASEPRODNAME
        ,_PRDDEFQTY
        ,_PURQTY
        ,_PURRETQTY
        ,_ISSUEQTY
        ,_DAMAGEQTY
        ,_BALQTY
        ,_MINESTIMATE
        ,_SALEQTY
        ,_MANUDAMAGEQTY
        ,_AVAILQTY
        ,'Sub Product' AS record_type
    FROM dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
    ) v1
ORDER BY _PRODNAME  ,
         _BASEPRODNAME;
```

Output is here

[image: Result]

Comment: your answer also full fill my requirement, but there are 4 select statement there and due to my records are in millions so it's giving me performance issue

Comment: @ImranAliKhan Thanks for the feedback. Even though there are 4 selects, only 2 inner selects reads the data from the database. I am keen to know what kind of performance you are seeing and whether you have managed to improve performance. If so, how you did it.

Comment: see my Accepted answer its neet and clean as per performance also

Answer (score 2):

**Demo**

http://rextester.com/AWO40913

**SQL**

```
SELECT _PRODNAME      AS [Manufacture Product],
       NULL           AS [Sub Product], 
       NULL           AS [Required Qty / Unit], 
       NULL           AS [Purchase Qty], 
       NULL           AS [Return Qty], 
       NULL           AS [Issue Qty], 
       NULL           AS [Damage Qty], 
       NULL           AS [Balance Qty], 
       _MINESTIMATE   AS [Estimate Qty], 
       _SALEQTY       AS [Sale Qty], 
       _MANUDAMAGEQTY AS Damage, 
       _AVAILQTY      AS [Avail Qty]
FROM   dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
WHERE _PRODNAME = 'Vanila Cake'
GROUP BY _PRODNAME, _MINESTIMATE, _SALEQTY, _MANUDAMAGEQTY, _AVAILQTY
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL      AS [Manufacture Product], 
       _BASEPRODNAME  AS [Sub Product], 
       _PRDDEFQTY     AS [Required Qty / Unit], 
       _PURQTY        AS [Purchase Qty], 
       _PURRETQTY     AS [Return Qty], 
       _ISSUEQTY      AS [Issue Qty], 
       _DAMAGEQTY     AS [Damage Qty], 
       _BALQTY        AS [Balance Qty], 
       NULL           AS [Estimate Qty], 
       NULL           AS [Sale Qty], 
       NULL           AS Damage, 
       NULL           AS [Avail Qty] 
FROM   dbo.VIEW_MANUFACTURING
WHERE _PRODNAME = 'Vanila Cake';
```

**Notes**

A `DISTINCT` could be used instead of a `GROUP BY` or even a simple `SELECT TOP 1`. `GROUP BY` was chosen out of these as it is faster than `DISTINCT` and would highlight any issues with the denormalized data.